# populating a field in excel using java HSSF POI - excel does not sort date field properly

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, poi-hssf

So I am populating an excel document using Java's HSSF POI and I am using a excel template which has some headers already entered into it like so...

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = readFile(TEMPLATE_LOCATION);
```

And my issue is that when I populate one of the columns with data in a date format of MM/dd/yyyy like so...

```
row.createCell((short)column++).setCellValue(Tools.dateToString(rfq.getCreationDate()));
```

It populates the column appropriately with data like....
01/01/2011
05/04/2010
03/03/2009

The bug is when I execute a sort on this column (in excel) using say an autofilter->sort ascending then it returns the dates in the wrong order like so....

01/01/2011

03/03/2009

05/04/2010

(As it is reading it like a string and sorting instead of sorting by a date)

I tried to set the column as a "Numeric" column and then sort still no dice....

```
        cell = row.createCell((short)column++);
        cell.setCellStyle(workbook.createCellStyle());
        cell.getCellStyle().setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
        cell.setCellValue(Tools.dateToString(rfq.getCreationDate()));
```

Also formating this way as well did not help...

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
row.createCell((short)column++).setCellValue(formatter.format(order.getCreationDate()));
```

This is all going on in Excel 2003.  No clue how to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are converting the data to strings when you populate the cells

```
row.createCell((short)column++).setCellValue(Tools.dateToString(rfq.getCreationDate()));
```

I'm not a java user, so not sure, but you could try just

```
row.createCell((short)column++).setCellValue(rfq.getCreationDate());
```

If the underlying data is in a form Excel recognises as a date, it should be ok.